# symbol as a property?

Tags: scheme, racket

structure definitions

So i'm asked to create a books (which is an ebook)  properties with a title, author, size, and a `symbol` designating the ebook as a `'Kindle, 'Nook, 'Nexus?` 
How would you put in a symbol and what exactly do they mean by it?

```
(define-struct book (ebook ))

(define-struct ebook (make-book title author size ??? ))
```

Answer (score 2):

It just means that you must use a [`symbol`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/symbols.html) as the data type for the ebook's brand. For example:

```
(define-struct ebook (title author size brand))

(define my-book (make-ebook "Cryptonomicon" "Neal Stephenson" 2192 'Kindle))
```

In the above code, `'Kindle` is a symbol denoting the brand of the ebook reader:

```
(ebook-brand my-book)
=> 'Kindle

(symbol? (ebook-brand my-book))
=> #t
```